# return a global variable in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to get the result of this algorithm called cartogram. This result is asynchronous, that is why it does not work with define a global variable. I need to get the json object that generates this: "features.features".

```
d3.json ("mapaoriginal.topojson" function (topology) {
                            var = cartogram features (topology, topology.objects.collection.geometries);
                            d3.select ("SVG")
                                .attr ("width", 1000)
                                .attr ("height", 500)
                              .selectAll ("path")
                                .data (features.features)
                                .enter ()
                              .append ("path")
                                .attr ("d" cartogram.path);
        })
```

My idea is to have something.

```
result = features.features;
```

and then use "result" outside the function.
if I define a global variable, it always appears undefined.
how I can get out of the function I need?

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that what is asynchronous is d3.json and not cartogram. If cartogram is asynchronous you have to check the documentation / code to identify if there is a way to provide a callback function for when the operation completes (otherwise you have to use a global event handler if that is possible of use `setInterval`  for periodically checking if the operation has completed - both are not recommended unless there is no other alternative)

> then use "result" outside the function.

`result` is initialized only once the asynchronous operation completes. So if you want to get the value, you have to wait for the callback (function) to start executing.

> if I define a global variable,
>   it always appears undefined. how I can get out of the function I need?

You can define a separate function to do what you want to do with `features.features` and call it in your callback. This will help keep your lines of code outside of the callback function.

Something like

```
d3.json ("mapaoriginal.topojson" function (topology) {
      // do current stuff
      // myFunction(features.features) that uses features.features
})

function myFunction(f) {
     // do stuff with f (features.features)
}
```

---

There is an alternative where you use a global even handler to listen for the JSON response or you set up a `setInterval` to check for the global variable value periodically - however this is almost always results in hard to maintain code and is NOT recommended.